# Where is the app directory and layout file in NextJS 13.3.4?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

So, I'm new to nextJS. I installed the latest version (13.3.4) using `npx create-next-app@latest` and it works, serves on port 3000 etc.

Now I'm learning about an app directory that houses some `layout.tsx` and `page.tsx` files, but I cannot find them in the project files.

I have checked their documentation, even manually adding the `app` directory and the layout and page files, and made changes to them, but nothing changed.

[image]

What is happening?

Update:

This is the next.config.js file

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, you need to create the ``app`` directory and these files manually !! More info https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

Comment: yep i did that but nothing changed

Comment: Can you show your `next.config.js` file content?

Comment: I just did that @YoussoufOumar

Comment: Below `reactStrictMode: true` and this `experimental: { appDir: true }`. But the thing is that you don't have any `app` folder yet. You may wanna recreate your project as the below answer said. Also, consider pasting codes as plain formatted text, not images :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do that, you have to run `npx create-next-app project` again. Then in the terminal, you'll be asked to either have the `app` directory or not.

Answer (score 1):

`create-next-app` comes with some options, run the following command to see

```
npx create-next-app@latest -h
```

among all the available options, there is an `--app` option

> --app
>
> Initialize as an App Router project.

so you can run with the `--app` option specified to make sure the `app` folder get created.

```bash
npx create-next-app@latest --app
```